# Marketing Cloud Connect - Scope by user - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We set up Marketing Cloud Connector with option "scope by user". Everything is working fine, but Salesforce Entry events in Journey Builder were only accessible **after** adding Salesforce.com Status to Integrated with a Sales Cloud user.

Now I'm wondering how scope by user is related to data that is accessible in Journey builder and I can't find any information in the documentation about that. I assumed that Scope by User is only related to Reports and Campaigns.

Does anyone know, if there are any restrictions in Journey Builder (available fields, fire on events for users), when using scope by user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scope by User does affect Journey Builder in that way, that Salesforce Entry Events can only be created by users who are integrated. If Scope by User is configured, and a user that is not integrated, creates a Salesforce Entry Event, an error message will appear "There was a problem retrieving the Integration Status".

If integrated, scope by user does not affect the available data. The reason is, that with a salesforce entry event, a process and flow are created by Sales Cloud API User in Sales Cloud and though, the scope by user permissions do not affect who is injected into a journey.
The only option to filter, is to use a a filter in the entry event or a decision split in the journey. It might be possible to adapt the created flow and process but I doubt that and didn't try this.

Related to that, in the Marketing Cloud June 2019 release, an option was introduced to restrict access to Salesforce events and activities in journey builder https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_june_2019_grant_separate_sf_events_activities_permissions.htm&type=5

Answer (score -1):

Scope by user option does affect journeys, automations and syn DEs

Comment: Thanks for you answer Pardeep. Meanwhile I found out, that Scope by User does not affect the available fields or if an entry event is triggered on the one side. On the other, it is not possible to configure a Salesforce Entry Event, if the Marketing Cloud User is not integrated when Scope By User is activated. How would Scope by user affect automations and synchronized DEs?

Comment: connected SF user's permissions/access to Objects and fields would be reflected in SFMC Sync'ed DEs and subsequent automations linked with these DEs